# Should this code cause a warning

Tags: c++, warnings, static-analysis

I came across code similar to that below which is legal, albeit not very clever.  Two stack variables in the same function in scope at the same time with the same name is legal but it can cause problems.  (Read: I just wasted half an hour debugging this).  At warning level 4 on VS2010 (the highest level), I would have hoped it would have caught this kind of thing.  Am I missing something, or is it time to hit to whole code base with lint for a once over?  Would a static analysis tool such as lint even pick up name clashes like this?

```
   char *x = strchr(Buffer,' ');
   if (x)
   {
     *x = 0;
     x++;
     char *x = strchr(x,' ') 
     if (x)
        *x = 0;
   }
```

Comment: GCC does better on this AFAIR ...

Comment: they're not of the same scope.  one `x` is function scope, one is block scope.

Comment: I don't think is easy for this to cause a warning. Many times it's the thing someone wants (e.g. formal parameter name and class member - usually you don't want to invent new names)

Comment: @Ghita "usually you don't want to invent new names" why not?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore void Setter(value val){ this->val = val; }

Comment: @Ghita I know you can, but why wouldn't you want a new name for `val`? What if your example isn't just a one-liner. What if it's spread across multiple screens, and a maintainer comes in later to debug and see a `val = something;`. He'll no doubt assume it's the member, not the local variable.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Yeas, in that case sucks. But for "properties" I prefer to be lazy..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PC-Lint](http://www.gimpel.com) will detect this. The following code:

```
main (int argc, char *argv []) 
{
    char *x = 0;
    if (x)
    {
        char *x = 0;
    }
}
```

Gives a warning:

```
main.cpp  6  Warning 578: Declaration of symbol 'x' hides symbol 'x' (line 3)
```

Comment: Weak rule. So many people write like this. There will be many false positives.

Comment: @AndreyCpp Still not a good idea. There is a reason this rule is part of MISRA.  Likewise, it's a routine check in all the static analysis tools I've used. Take a look at this link: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/DCL01-C.+Do+not+reuse+variable+names+in+subscopes

Comment: Time to dig out my copy of PC-Lint again.  I used to use it regularly but have gotten out of the habit,

Comment: @AndreyCpp - Not sure if you're arguing against using PC-Lint or not. There is no issue with false positives if you normally code like this, because PC-Lint has complete configurability to shut off any error you wish.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** I didn't notice this when I wrote the original answer (below). The code you've posted is illegal, and causes undefined behavior. The offending line is this one:

```
char *x = strchr(x,' ');
```

Here the `x` within the `strchr` call **does not** refer to the `x` defined in the enclosing scope, but to the `x` defined previously on the same line. Hence that line reads from an uninitialized variable, which results in undefined behavior. From the C++ standard,

> §3.3.2/1 *[basic.scope.pdecl]*
> The *point of declaration* for a name is immediately after its complete declarator (Clause 8) and before its *initializer* (if any), except as noted below. [ Example:
>
> ```
>    int x = 12;
>    { int x = x; }
> ```
>
> Here the second x is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value. —end example ]

GCC does complain if the corresponding line in the example below is changed to

```
int x = 21 + x; // generates "warning: x is used uninitialized in this function"
```

And duplicating your `strchr` example on VS2012 generates this warning (at `/W1` and above):

```
warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'x' used
```

---

Original answer follows (not entirely accurate):

There's nothing illegal about the code. You've introduced a new scope by adding braces, and you're allowed to define variables within the new scope even if those variable names have been previously defined in the enclosing scope.

All references to the variable after the new definition will refer to the local variable instead of the one in the enclosing scope, until the lifetime of the local variable ends. The following code produces no warnings on GCC even when compiled with `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra`

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int x = 42;
  {
      std::cout << x << '\n';
      int x = 21;
      std::cout << x << '\n';
  }
  std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
42
21
42
```

I don't know whether lint or another static analysis tool will pick out such things either. It is legal, but not advisable.

Comment: Yikes, you're original answer was actually correct and the issue in my example was unintentional, but thanks for the edited answer anyway.  I'll leave my question as is, warts and all, as your answer is useful in that context.